# How to disable timer on MSP430?

Tags: pwm, timer, msp430

I am new to the TI MSP430G2553. I would like to send a PWM signal like in this picture:

<sub>(Image source: [Adafruit - Understanding Infrared Signals](https://learn.adafruit.com/infrared-transmit-and-receive-on-circuit-playground-express-in-c-plus-plus-2/understanding-infrared-signals))</sub>

However I can't do that, because I don't know how to stop (finish) the PWM signal.
Here is my PWM signal code:

```
void configTimer(void)  // this function sends infinite pwm signal when button is pressed  
{
TA1CCR0 = 26-1;                          // Period 
  TA1CCR1 = 13;                            // 50% dutycycle
  TA1CCTL1 |= OUTMOD_6;                    //  Reset/Set
  TA1CTL = TASSEL_1 + MC_1 + TACLR; 
}
```

I tried:

1. `TA1CTL1=0;`
2. `TA1CTL = MC_0;`
3. set default value of `TA1CCR1 = 0`, when button pressed set `TA1CCR1 = 13;` and later `__delay_cycles(any number);`

However they didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: My last try
Edit2: Edit: I think can't use my timer interrupt my counter is always 0.

?

## define TIMER0_A1_VECTOR    (8u * 2u)  /* 0xFFF0 Timer0)A CC1, TA0 */

## define TIMER0_A0_VECTOR    (9u * 2u)  /* 0xFFF2 Timer0_A CC0 */

This is definiton of timer0 vector. How should i write it in my code?

```
#include <msp430.h>

void startTimer(void);

unsigned char counter=0;

void start2Timer(void);

int main(void)
{
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer
BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ; // Set range
DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ; 
CCTL0 = CCIE; 

P2DIR |= BIT2;
P2SEL |= BIT2;// Select pwm  pin (transmitter)
       
P2OUT=0x00;


while(1){

if((P1IN & BIT4)!=BIT4) //button is pressed
  {
 startTimer(); 
 start2Timer();
  }
  
}

}

void startTimer(void) // pwm signal
{
TA1CCR0 = 26-1;                          // Period Register
  TA1CCR1 = 13;                            // TA1.1 25% dutycycle
  TA1CCTL1 |= OUTMOD_6;                    // TA1CCR1, Reset/Set
  TA1CTL = TASSEL_1 + MC_1 + TACLR;
}


void start2Timer(void) // trying to stop after 50 ms
{
CCR0 = 5000; // CCR0 5 ms 
TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_2; // 
}

#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR // Timer0_A0 
__interrupt void Timer_A (void)
{
if(++counter==10){ // is counter 10 (5*10=ms)
 TA1CCR1 = 0;   ; // Stop pwm 
counter = 0;
} 
}
```

Comment: `TA1CTL = MC_0` should work. What actually happened when you tried that?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. In the question, you said the problem is you can't stop the timer. Setting `TA1CTL=MC_0` should stop the timer. If you have a different issue, you should edit the question to explain what the issue is.

Comment: If you're using `delay_cycles()` to produce delay between output changes, you don't need to use the timer. You can use the timer when you want to change the output without your code writing to P2OUT. Also, if you have the pin configured as a timer pin, writing to P2OUT won't change the state of the pin. If you have the pin configured as a GPIO pin, then the timer can't control it.

Comment: Basically, it looks like you're trying to control the output with two different and conflicting mechanisms at the same time. You need to choose whether to let the timer control the pin, or control it using the P2OUT register. You can't do both at the same time. What do you have in the P2MAP registers?

Comment: Thanks i tried something new. And edited my question. Can you look at it please?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to turn off the timer:

TA1CTL &= ~(MC_1) ;//or whatever mode the timer is running at

Comment: `TA1CTL &= ~MC` is better, because it will stop the timer regardless of what mode it was in.